# Path to media on Cordova Window Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

My WP8 Cordova project can't play audio from pakage.  However, it works if I build the same code for Cordova WP7 with path `'app/www/FILE'`.  External audio works to. But what is the correct local path to media on Cordova WP8?